# How to get url from a new window by using Selenium with phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I want to get a new window url by using selenium, and using PhantomJs is more efficient than Firefox.
  python code is here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
renren = webdriver.Firefox()
#renren = webdriver.PhantomJS()
renren.get("file:///home/xjz/Desktop/html/easy.html")
renren.execute_script("windows()")
now_handle1 = renren.current_window_handle
all_handles1 = renren.window_handles
for handle1 in all_handles1:
    if handle1 != now_handle1:
        renren.switch_to_window(handle1)
        print renren.current_url
        print renren.page_source
```

In script "windows()", it will open a new window for http://www.renren.com/.
  When I use Firefox,I get current url and context of http://www.renren.com/ .     But I get "about:blank" of the url and "" of the context.It means I get failed when I use PhantomJS.
  So how can I get current url when I use selenium with PhantomJS.
  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you check with sleep time before getting the current URL?

Comment: Thank you very much,it work well :) , you help me a lot!!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will be happy if you accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add sleep time in your code before getting the current URL.

```
from selenium import webdriver
renren = webdriver.Firefox()
...
...
...
import time
    time.sleep(10)# in seconds
    print renren.current_url
..
```